# Using specific elements from a list in different loops for a multiple choice test python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, list

Basically i'm trying to create a multiple choice test that uses information stored inside of lists to change the questions/ answers by location.

so far I have this

```
import random

DATASETS = [["You first enter the car", "You start the car","You reverse","You turn",
         "Coming to a yellow light","You get cut off","You run over a person","You have to stop short",
         "in a high speed chase","in a stolen car","A light is broken","The car next to you breaks down",
         "You get a text message","You get a call","Your out of gas","Late for work","Driving angry",
         "Someone flips you the bird","Your speedometer stops working","Drinking"],
        ["Put on seat belt","Check your mirrors","Look over your shoulder","Use your turn signal",
         "Slow to a safe stop","Relax and dont get upset","Call 911", "Thank your brakes for working",
         "Pull over and give up","Ask to get out","Get it fixed","Offer help","Ignore it","Ignore it",
         "Get gas... duh","Drive the speed limit","Don't do it","Smile and wave","Get it fixed","Don't do it"],
        [''] * 20,
        ['B','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D','B','C','D','A','D','C','C','B','D','A'],
        [''] * 20]

def main():

    questions(0)
    answers(1)

def questions(pos):
    for words in range(len(DATASETS[0])):
        DATASETS[2][words] = input("\n" + str(words + 1) + ".)What is the proper procedure when %s" %DATASETS[0][words] +
                        '\nA.)'+random.choice(DATASETS[1]) + '\nB.)%s' %DATASETS[1][words] + '\nC.)'
                        +random.choice(DATASETS[1]) + '\nD.)'+random.choice(DATASETS[1])+
                        "\nChoose your answer carefully: ")

def answers(pos):
    for words in range(len(DATASETS[0])):
        DATASETS[4] = list(x is y for x, y in zip(DATASETS[2], DATASETS[3]))
    print(DATASETS)
```

I apologize if the code is crude to some... i'm in my first year of classes and this is my first bout of programming.
list 3 is my key for the right answer's, I want my code in questions() to change the position of the correct answer so that it correlates to the key provided....

I've tried for loops, if statements and while loops but just cant get it to do what I envision. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    tmp = "\n" + str(words + 1) + ".)What is the proper procedure when %s" %DATASETS[0][words] + '\nA.)'
    if DATASETS[3][words] == 'A': #if the answer key is A
      tmp = tmp + DATASETS[1][words] #append the first choice as correct choice
    else:
      tmp = tmp + random.choice(DATASETS[1]) #if not, randomise the choice
```

Do similar if-else for 'B', 'C', and 'D'
Once your question is formulated, then you can use it:

```
DATASETS[2][words] = input(tmp)
```

This is a bit long but I am not sure if any shorter way exists.

Comment: This did it, I didn't know if there was a one liner that i was missing to accomplish it and i couldn't wrap my head around if and elif. i figured that had to be the answer but i just couldn't get it right. i think its time to walk away for the night.